# How to use XOR to Encrypt a music file

Tags: iphone, c

I want to encrypt and decrypt 10000 bytes of a music file. I used the code :

```
if(file!=NULL && g!= NULL)  
{
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        count++;
        char aByte;
        fread(&aByte, sizeof(char), 1, file);
        if (count <= 10000)
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                if ((aByte ^ 'A') != EOF) aByte = aByte ^ 'A';
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((aByte ^ 'B') != EOF) aByte = aByte ^ 'B';
            }
        }
        fwrite(&aByte, sizeof(char), 1, g);
    }
}   
fclose(file);
```

But the code does not work. Please help!!!

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Becase after run encrypt 2 times. The file can not run(listening).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your file handling by removing the "encryption".  Take out these lines

```
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            if ((aByte ^ 'A') != EOF) aByte = aByte ^ 'A';
        }
        else 
        {
            if ((aByte ^ 'B') != EOF) aByte = aByte ^ 'B';
        }
```

Is your file the exact same?  I think it will not be.  Here are some reasons

1. The file is longer than 10,000 bytes -- you close file at the end, so I assume that those bytes are lost
2. The file is less than 10,000 bytes -- you don't check for EOF property, so it looks like an extra byte will be written
3. count is not initialized in this code -- if it's odd on one run and even on another, it wont' match.  Also, it's just going to copy a random number of bytes depending on what count is.  Perhaps it's initialized elsewhere.
4. You don't close g, so you can't be sure it was flushed (fwrite can buffer writes)

UPDATE: EOF is not a byte that you can find in a file, it's a special return value used by some FILE API functions (not fread).

The function getchar() is defined like this:

```
  int getchar();
```

It either returns EOF or an int that is within the range of char.  If it's EOF, then that means that you are at the end of the file. If not, you may safely cast the return to a char.  The only stipulation on EOF is that it isn't a valid char.  getchar() returns an int because it can return any char (256 choices) + EOF for a total of 257 choices which can't be represented in a char.

If you look at fread(), you will see that it doesn't have anything to do with chars.  It takes a buffer, and record size, and a record count and returns the number of bytes read.  You happen to be passing in sizeof(char) and 1 to get a char.  It couldn't possibly store EOF in that char because EOF is not a valid char, it's an int and won't fit.  It doesn't use the same conventions as getchar(). If it encounters EOF, it returns a number less than the total number of bytes requested. In your case, that's 0.  If fread() returns 0, check feof() and ferror() to find out if you got to the end-of-file or got an error (both cause fread to return less than the number requested).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do the XOR when you're checking for `EOF` (which, by the way, `fread` indicates in its return value rather than in the value it writes to your buffer); only when you're preparing the byte to be written to the file.

Also, you'll need a much longer key if you want to encrypt it properly — and the key must be unknown to anyone who isn't supposed to be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Sr. I'm not understand. But i check for EOF because i don't want to write EOF to file. If the byte xor with key makes a result EOF i will write the byte to file.

Comment: I would just remove the `feof()` call and instead check the return value of `fread` each time you call it. If it returns zero, there's no more data, so you break out of the loop.

Comment: while(!feof(file)). SR this checking is not enough?

Comment: It would be enough if you were using it correctly, but in your particular case it'd be better just to check the return value of `fread`. That way, you don't have to go `if (aByte != EOF)`. (Which won't work, in any case, since `aByte` would have to be an integer.)

Comment: To clarify the above comment: Your problem seems to be that you're mixing different (valid) ways of reading bytes in C. You should just pick one -- maybe look at some example code and only add the XOR stuff once you've got it to read and write characters properly.

Comment: Sr i don't check aByte != EOF, i checked : aByte ^ 'A' != EOF. I think this way to avoid meet the feof() and write it to file.

Comment: I know, and I've already explain why **that** isn't right. Try editing your post to update your code based on the suggestions already posted, and then we'll see if it's better.

Comment: EOF is not a char, you can't possibly write it to the file. aByte cannot possibly be EOF.  You need to check the result of fread.